# Enter Key on Infragistics Editable Wingrid

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a screen containing infragistics windows editable grid and winforms button.
On Enter key, the new row gets added in ultrawin grid. Instead i need to fire winforms button event.

Only on tab, it should navigate to next cell and when it reaches last cell, it should navigate to next row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle UltraGrid's [BeforeRowUpdate](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~BeforeRowUpdate_EV.html) event and invoke UltraButton's perform click before the new row template is about to be commited.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool _IsEnterKeyDown = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ultraGrid1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ultraGrid1_KeyDown);
        ultraGrid1.BeforeRowUpdate += new CancelableRowEventHandler(ultraGrid1_BeforeRowUpdate);
        ultraGrid1.InitializeLayout += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventHandler(ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout);
        ultraGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            _IsEnterKeyDown = true;
        }
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_BeforeRowUpdate(object sender, CancelableRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.IsAddRow && _IsEnterKeyDown)
        {
            _IsEnterKeyDown = false;
            ultraButton1.PerformClick();
        }
    }

    private void ultraButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button click event raised!");
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Layout.Override.AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.TemplateOnBottom;
    }

    private DataTable GetDataTable(int rows = 10)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Table1");

        table.Columns.Add("Boolean column", typeof(bool));
        table.Columns.Add("Integer column", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("DateTime column", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("String column", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Boolean column"] = i % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
            row["Integer column"] = i;
            row["String column"] = "text";
            row["DateTime column"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```